# SingleChildScrollView with Column of Flexible Cards: "A RenderFlex Overflowed by x pixels on bottom", How to make card expand?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a list of cards that are displayed in a SingleChildScrollView.
However I can't figure out how to make the cards fit their contents.

I've attached a picture of my issue, and how I want the cards to look like.

I've tried putting them in an expanded which doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've also tried setting a manual height on the card container which for some reason only displays two cards and doesn't let me scroll.

I'm presuming that I need to set a minimum height on the cards, but I can't seem to figure out at what level should I add it.

```dart
Widget displayVideo(item) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(item.fromChannel.channelThumbnail),
                ),
                title: Text(item.fromChannel.channelTitle),
                subtitle: Text(item.publishAt),
              ),
              Container(
                child: new AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 10,
                  child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                      image: new NetworkImage(item.thumbnailUrl),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    item.title,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget displayVideos(items) {
    List<Widget> lines = [];
    print(items);
    items.videos.forEach((element) => lines.add(displayVideo(element)));

    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(children: lines)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ExplorePlaylistArguments args =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    playlist = fetchPlaylist(args.playlistId);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(args.playlistName),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<Playlist>(
              future: playlist,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return displayVideos(snapshot.data);
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }),
        ));
  }
```

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 303 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/Jonathan/AndroidStudioProjects/klp_app/lib/screens/explore_playlist.dart:29:18
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#42b06 relayoutBoundary=up19 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=384.7, 0.0<=h<=67.9)
...  size: Size(384.7, 67.9)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 303 pixels on the bottom.
```

How the cards look like:

[image: How it's looks like]

How I want each individual card to look like:

[image: How I want the cards to look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Widget displayVideo(item) {
return Card(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage:
              NetworkImage(item.fromChannel.channelThumbnail),
        ),
        title: Text(item.fromChannel.channelTitle),
        subtitle: Text(item.publishAt),
      ),
      new AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: Image.network(item.thumbnailUrl, fit:BoxFit.fitWidth),
          ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(
         item.title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}

Widget displayVideos(items) {
   List<Widget> lines = [];
   items.forEach((element) => lines.add(displayVideo(element)));

   return SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(children: lines));
}
```

Tip: You can also use [`ListView.builder()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) instead of `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column`

Comment: Thanks Kumar! I that fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

You have to **remove Container** from **displayVideos** method.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(children: lines)); // container remove
```

And **remove Flexible** from **displayVideo method**.

Comment: Thanks Viren! I appreciate the solution!

Comment: what fixed the overflow on the card?  did the aspect ratio or the list builder fix the problem